# Passing parameter from a bat to a bat (environment variable)

Tags: variables, parameters, batch-file, environment

I need to pass some parameters from a bat, `file1.bat` to another bat, `file2.bat`. Problem is that `@echo %2` inside `file2.bat` shows `""` from prompt command, so the variable named `secondVar` defined inside `file1.bat` is not being send as it should be, while the first argument is always sending successfully.

I'm stuck here therefore i cannot go ahead.The goal of the 
     call file2.bat "aFile" !secondVar! 
is searching for the secondVar variable into aFile for each secondVar.

Please someone could tell me what is happening and give me something right. Thank you very much in advance!

**file2.bat** looks like:

```
@echo off
echo %2
Set arg1=%1
echo %arg1%
cscript process.vbs %1>result
more +1  %1|findstr /I /r /b /C:"^T.*=%2">viewout
```

**file1.bat** looks like:

```
@echo off & setLocal
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set secondVar=%secondVar%

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (myFile) do (set secondVar="%%a"
echo !secondVar!
call file2.bat "aFile" !secondVar!
)
```

Comment: Does the variable appear at `echo !secondVar!` in file1.bat?

Comment: yes, it appears at the console from file.bat. But It does not retrieve when calling file2.bat from file1.bat

Comment: I have found my error. Instead of writing 'set secondVar="%%a"' into file1.bat, I have written 'set secondVar=%%a' (%%a without no quotes and it's works fine now!). even if I don't know why!!!!  Thanks all

Comment: You should better use `set "secondVar=%%a"`. :)

Comment: Sorry, it does not solve my problem. Indeed the variable 'a' contains a text(not a single string), for example "I take breakfast"). Using set "secondVar=%%a", I only retrieve "I" and not all strings. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In **File1.bat**, change

```
set secondVar="%%a"
```

to

```
set secondVar="%%~a"
```

The use of the *tilde* character first removes enclosing double-quotes...

You could also use: set "secondVar=%%~a"

Comment: The use of your solution meet some problems. if the variable 'a' meets "I have breakfast" in (myFile), only "I" is pull out in file2.bat(see echo %2) even though in file1.bat, echo !secondVar! shows "I have breakfast" as expected. It's very strange for me!! Likewise, replacing the variable 'a' by "k^cd^" is showing "k^cd^" as expected into file1.bat but removing "^" in file2.bat is showing "kcd"